# Cannot deserialize object graph into object with inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, ajax, json, web-services, inheritance

I have an Webservice including the folowing method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void saveDayEntries(List<DayEntry> listofEntries, string language)
{...}
```

There is a inheritance hierarchy like that:
DayEntry->DataEntry->DayEntryLD

And there is an interface, so I have to take DayEntry and can't take DayEntryLD.

On the client side, I create an Array from the type of DayEntryLD and send it to the Webservice/saveDayEntries like this:

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DataProviderFD.asmx/saveDayEntries",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: "{'listofEntries':" + JSON.stringify(data) + ", 'language': '" + lang + "'}"
    });
```

If I execute the code I get the following error:
"Cannot deserialize object graph into type of DayEntry"

I think I understand the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
Does anyone have experience with this? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried annotating the service method with the XmlInclude attribute? you need to specify such an attribute for every derived type in the hierarchy.

```
[WebMethod]
public void saveDayEntries(List<DayEntry> listofEntries, string language){}

[XmlInclude(typeof(DataEntry))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DataEntryLD))]
class DayEntry{}
```

Comment: I get this error, while compiling: "Attribute 'KnownType' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on class,struct declarations."

Comment: sorry. add these to the base type DayEntry

Comment: Thanks alot. But I do get the same exception. "Can't deserialize..."

Comment: KnownType is for WCF. I think you need to use XmlInclude for classic web services. if this doesn't work either, i give up :)

Comment: hi again :) . i just tested the XmlInclude. this works on my side. i made a classic web service and used XmlInclude to include the derived types. i successfully consumed the service from a console app in c#. when using KnownType the derived types weren't even created on the client. XmlInclude is the way to go on the server. something else must be missing. do you have the [ScriptService] attribute on the service class? also, i don't know much about js but are you sure the client code is correct?